# Flutter - Get location while app is minimized (background) - Every x seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, background, location, dart-isolates

I'm trying to get location every 7 seconds, and I'm using the below Isolate to do the job.

The isolate itself works pretty well when the app is minimized (I could see the counter value being printed to console). But, the location values are not returned.

Has anyone identified a better solution to get location data in the background, continously.

```
void startIsolate() async {
    _receivePort = ReceivePort();
    _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_checkTimer, _receivePort!.sendPort);
    _receivePort!.listen(
      _handleMessage,
      onDone: () {
        print('done!');
      },
    );
  }

  void stopIsolate() => _stop();

  static void _checkTimer(SendPort sendPort) async {
    Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 7),
      (Timer t) async {
        _counter++;
        var task = _counter;
        sendPort.send(task);
      },
    );
  }

  void _handleMessage(dynamic data) async {
    print('RECEIVED: $data');
    bool hasPermissions =
        await checkLocationPermissions(_myLocation!).then((value) => value);

    _myLocation = Location();

    if (hasPermissions) {
      _myLocation!
          .getLocation()
          .then((locationData) => {setLocationData(locationData)});
      _myLocation!.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
        setLocationData(locationData);
      });
    }
  }
```

Best Regards
Sivakumar Kumar